# Ruby - Wrong number of arguments 0 for 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to Update a single record but I'm getting 'Wrong number of arguments' error.

I'm using Postman to try it out throught this url> localhost:3000/confirmations/32 (PUT Method)

**My controller 'confirmation_controller'**

```
def update

        @confirmation = Invite.find(params[:id])
        #if params[:estado] == 'Confirmar'
            @confirmation.estado = 'Confirmado' 
        #elsif params[:estado] == 'Cancelar'
            #@confirmation.estado = 'Cancelado'
        #end
        if @confirmation.update
            @user = User.joins(:postulation).where(:postulation => {:id => @confirmation.postulation_id})
            #Tengo que pasarle el usuario que le confirmo
            UserNotifier.send_confirmation_to_user(@confirmation, @user)
        end
    end
```

**My routes**

```
resources :confirmations, only: [:index, :update, :edit]
```

The main idea is that the user will have a button 'Confirm' and when it is pressed will change the status of an invite. So I'm trying to simple update that field. I can't understand why I'm not able to get the param.

thanks a lot.

Comment: [Your use of `update` is wrong](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update). You should use `save` instead or write `@confirmation.update(estado: 'Confirmado')`

Comment: hi, Thanks. Do you have a link with an example of 'save' method which I can follow? Thanks

Comment: what you get if you print `@confirmation` (`puts @confirmation.inspect` ) after `@confirmation.estado` line?

Answer (score 0):

like someone said before, you should be using:
@confirmation.save (or .save!)

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/save
That will run through the model validations and save any changes to the object to db.